# Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order::getCollection()

Tags: magento-1.9, php, blocks

I am having issues getting a collection from the DB in Magento.

I am trying to pull the field `rx_queue` from the table `sales_flat_order` (it's a custom column we added).

When I run the function that is supposed to do this, I get the error message listed in the title of this question.

Here is the function

```
public function getPrescriptionQueue($orderId) {
    $prescription = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('increment_id', array('eq' => $orderId))->getSelect();
    return $prescription['rx_queue'];
}
```

What am I doing that gives me this error in the first place? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please keep in my mind this thing

```
Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order'); ==  Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
```

So If you are using resource model it has already called getCollection Method so you dont have to call it again

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was using `Mage::getResourceModel` where I should have used `Mage::getModel`